# using simple numbers to assign colors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I wonder if it is possible to create a number system to assign colors in different graphs, something like `col = 1` rather than `color = "red"`. I don't really mind about specific colors used as long as they are consistent between  graphs. I feel that numbers might be easier to work with than strings when on many graphs. For example, I would like to the following 3 graphs to have the same color for `class = "compact"`:

```
library(tidyverse) 
#1
mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, col = class)) +
    geom_point() 
# 2
mpg %>% 
  filter(!class %in% c("2seater", "pickup")) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, col = class)) +
        geom_point()
# 3    
mpg %>% 
  filter(class == "compact") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_line(color = "?")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to ensure that the same color maps to a specific variable is to use `scale_color_manual()` with a named vector of colors, where the names are the variables.

For example, you can assign the values of `mpg$class` to a palette of 7 colors using `purrr::set_names`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

group.colors <- set_names(rainbow(7), unique(mpg$class))

group.colors
    compact     midsize         suv     2seater     minivan      pickup  subcompact 
"#FF0000FF" "#FFDB00FF" "#49FF00FF" "#00FF92FF" "#0092FFFF" "#4900FFFF" "#FF00DBFF"
```

Now `compact` will always be red.

```
mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, col = class)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = group.colors)
```

[image]

```
mpg %>% 
  filter(!class %in% c("2seater", "pickup")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, col = class)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = group.colors)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's great to learn this useful approach. It appears that I still need to find the color and assign it explicitly in #3.

Comment: #3 will work just the same: `mpg %>% filter(class == "compact") %>% ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, color = class)) + geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values = group.colors)`

Comment: Got it, genius!